# Can't use OpenCV namespace

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I'm trying to install OpenCV and thought I was done... But this has errors:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
}
```

`Error: Symbol 'cv' could not be resolved`

But apparently the two includes include just fine. The code itself is taken from an example on OpenCV.org so I assume the code is right. And I'm too n00b to diagnose what the problem is, only vaguely knowing what namespaces are...

Comment: Have you linked against the library? Did you really copy the includes into eclipse's include directory? Are there any other errors? What OS are you using? For [reference](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not including the C++ headers but the C ones.
You should try to include files such as `highgui.hpp`, or the global `opencv2.hpp` instead.

If these files do not exist, you have to upgrade for a more recent version of the library.
If they exist but your compiler can't find them, you have to use the `-I/path/to/include` option when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

You sure you're using a C++ compiler and not a C compiler? The code compiles fine from command line, e.g.,:

```
g++ -o opencv opencv.cpp -I/usr/include/opencv
```

Johan.

Comment: If it would be a `C`-compiler it would have complained about `using` and `namespace`...

Answer (score 0):

You should include in the first space /usr/local/include in GCC C++ Compiler. See the next picture.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

I should have mentioned that I a running Linux. The problem was that I didn't have the library path configured. See section "Path Configuration" in this guide: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide_Linux

Comment: that link is dead. What exactly did you have to do to set "Path Configuration" ?

Comment: What did you do to fix it ? the link is dead.

Comment: Please fix the link or improve your answer.