# Undefined functions in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
#include<opencv2\videoio.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(){

    Mat image;
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);
    namedwindow("window",1);
    while(1){
        cap>>image;
        imshow("window",image);
        waitKey(33);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when i try to run the program above i get the error that identifiers "namedWindow", "imshow" and "waitkey" are undefined.
i am coding in  visual studio 2010.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299822/cant-use-opencv-namespace

Comment: use the `c++` `includes`
    `#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including obsolete C code. To include the correct headers, use `opencv2` and correct path.

Note that you can avoid all these includes, using the *include all*: `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/video/video.hpp>

// or use only: #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(){

    Mat image;
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);
    namedWindow("window", 1);
    while (1){
        cap >> image;
        imshow("window", image);
        waitKey(33);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering, it did solve my problem but now i have a new error "error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core243.lib'.

Comment: you're not linking correctly to your libs. Also, you're using a very old version of OpenCV. I recommend to upgrade to version 3.1

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
```

you have to use different, `C` functions, like `cvNamedWindow("title");` and `cvShowImage("title", img);`

Use the following `C++` includes:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
```

(you dont'h have to use all of them ...)